# Product of the two subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

These are problems bothering me.

Let $S$ and $T$ are subrings of a ring $R$.

And $I$ and $J$ are ideals of the $R$.

**Question 1**

Let product of subrings like ideal product $IJ$ which means

$ST = \{ s_1t_1+s_2t_2+...+s_nt_n \vert s_k \in S , t_k \in T, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

This $ST$ might be not subring of the $R$ so I've tried to find the counterexample of this but I failed.

**Questuion 2**

When ideal case, $IJ$ is the subring of $I \cap J$

Then generally, if $ST$ is a subring of $R$, is $ST$ subring of  the $S\cap T$?

Please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example is $S =k[x]$ and T = $k[y]$ inside of the noncommutative polynomial ring $k\langle x,y\rangle$. So for instance $xyxy \not\in ST$, but its is a valid product of two elements in $ST$.

The issue comes from noncommutativity; if $S$ and $T$ commute in the larger ring then $ST$ will be a ring. (Or more generally if you can rewrite $ts = s’t’$, or in other words if $TS \subseteq ST$.)

No we don’t have $ST \subset S \cap T$, this property for ideals requires absorptivity, which subrings in general lack. For instance in the example above $S\cap T = k$ is much smaller than $ST$. And izf your subrings contain identity then $S\cup T \subset ST$ so there is no way its contained in $S\cap T$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I haven't thought noncommutativity.